# Having troubles figuring out how to implement spaces in between words. Right now I have underscores instead

Tags: python, python-3.6

My code is suppose to take a phrase from a file. I currently have it working, but I can't seem to figure out how I can change my output. In my output I have underscores for spaces in between words. I want the output to have actual spaces instead of underscores. In my code I have each character replace with an underscore. I think this is my problem because it is reading the blank spaces as characters also. My goal is to figure out with some help on how I can't stop this from happening.

Update: The problem was fixed so far. Now there is a underscore at the end of each phrase now. Any suggestions?

```
    #Define a filename
filename = "puzzles.txt".lower()

#Imports
import random

#Open the file and read
with open(filename) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    randomSecretPhrase = (random.choice(lines)) #Choose random phrase from file
    #***Output secret word to screen test***
    print(randomSecretPhrase)

#Initalize        
correct = []
incorrect = []
guesses = []
count = 0

def game():
    for i in randomSecretPhrase:
        if i in correct:
            print(i,end=' ')
        elif i != ' ':
            print('_',end=' ')
        else:
            print(' ',end=' ')
    print("\n\n")
    print('Number of times guessed: ', count)
    print('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~')

def guessed_letters():
#Will check the user input to verify valid letter is entered
    while True:
        guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()
        if guess in correct or guess in incorrect:
            print("You have already guessed that letter. Please guess again.")
            print(count)
        elif guess.isnumeric():
            print("Please enter only letters not numbers! Guess again.")
        elif len(guess) > 1:
            print("Please enter only one letter at a time. Please guess again.")
        elif len(guess) == 0:
            print("Please enter a letter.")
        else:
            break

#Keep track of correct and incorrect guesses

    if guess in randomSecretPhrase:
        correct.append(guess)
        print('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~')
        print("You have guessed correctly!")
        print('\n')
    else:
        print('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~')
        incorrect.append(guess)
        print("You have guessed incorrectly!")
        print('\n')

#Main program
while True:
    #Call game()
    game()
    #Call guessed_letters()
    guessed_letters()
    #Count how many times guesses
    count += 1






Output:
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Guess a letter: h
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
You have guessed correctly!


b a c k   i n   a   f l a s h _ 


Number of times guessed:  10
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of these will get rid of the underscores. You are correct that it is iterating over the spaces as well.

```
def game():
for i in randomSecretPhrase:
    if i in correct:
        print(i,end=' ')
    elif i in string.ascii_letters:
        print('_',end=' ')
    else:
        # Print an extra space between words
        print(' ')
```

Or, if you don't want to have extra spaces in between the words you could:

```
def game():
for i in randomSecretPhrase.replace(' ', ''):
    if i in correct:
        print(i,end=' ')
    elif:
        print('_',end=' ')
```

You probably also want to prevent the player from guessing spaces.

Comment: Oh okay. I see what you did. Now with the output there is one underscore at the end now.

Comment: Their is any underscore at the end thou.

Comment: Maybe you have a non-letter, non-space character at the end. Try changing the `elif i != ' ':` to `elif i in string.ascii_letters`. You can `import string` at the top of the file.

Comment: What is the string.ascii_letters doing by the way?

Comment: string.ascii_letters returns the string `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`. So by checking if i is in ascii_letters you are ensuring that it is a character in the  english alphabet. More info here. https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html